# SQL query can't return resuilt to fit

Tags: sql

I have 4 tables:

Table **HOUSE**

```
ID_HOUSE (auto inc)
Name_House (string)
```

Table **Room**

```
ID_HOUSE
ID_Room (auto inc)
Name_Room (string)
```

Table **Money_room**

```
Id (auto)
ID_Room
R_Money
Mounth(example: 02/20120)
status (0 or 1)
```

Table **Money_service**

```
Id(auto)
ID_Room
S_Money
Mounth(example: 02/20120)
status (0 or 1)
```

Now i want to print list all room with status is 1 (Money_room and Money_service) and user select Mounth from interface (@mounth). View resuilt in GridView:

```
Name_House      Name_Room        R_Money         S_Money          R_Money+ S_Money 
.....
.....
.....
.....
.....

                    Page  1  page 2  page 3  page 4.....
```

=> And at bottom of form (label of winform):  Total R_Money    Total S_Money   Total (R_S_Money)

I use  SQL=

```
select x.Name_House, y.Name_Room , sum ...  sum ....  
group by ... 
order by ... DESC
OFFSET " + PageSize * (page - 1) + " ROWS FETCH NEXT " + PageSize + " ROWS ONLY; "
```

But can't do that.

any body can help me!

my query is:

```
query = "Select H.Name_House, R.Name_Room, (select sum(isnull(R_Money, 0)) from Money_room  where ID_Room=R.ID_Room and  Mounth = @Mounth and status =1), 
(select sum(isnull(S_Money, 0)) from Money_service  where ID_Room=R.ID_Room and Mounth = @Mounth and status =1),  
(select sum(isnull(R_Money, 0)) from Money_room  where ID_Room=R.ID_Room and  Mounth = @Mounth and status =1) + 
(select sum(isnull(R_Money, 0)) from Money_service  where ID_Room=R.ID_Room and  Mounth = @Mounth and status =1),
(select sum(isnull(R_Money, 0)) over ()  from Money_room  where ID_Room=R.ID_Room and  Mounth = @Mounth and status =1) as MRTotal,
(select sum(isnull(R_Money, 0)) over () from Money_service  where ID_Room=R.ID_Room and Mounth = @Mounth and status =1)  as MSTotal, 
COUNT(*) OVER () AS total_count from Room R inner join HOUSE H on R.ID_HOUSE=H.ID_HOUSE ";

query += " group by R.ID_HOUSE,H.Name_House, R.Name_Room, R.ID_Room order by R.ID_HOUSE, R.Name_Room DESC OFFSET " + PageSize * (page - 1) + " ROWS FETCH NEXT " + PageSize + " ROWS ONLY; ";


  if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                lblNumberRecord.Text = " Have " + dt.Rows[0]["total_count"].ToString() + " records. ";

                TotalPage = (Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["total_count"]) + PageSize - 1) / PageSize;
                lblNumberpage.Text = "Page " + page + "/" + TotalPage;

                lbl1.Text = "Total Money room :   "  + String.Format("{0:#,##}", dt.Rows[0]["MRTotal"]);
                lbl2.Text = "Total Money_service :    "  +String.Format("{0:#,##}", dt.Rows[0]["MSTotal"]);

            }
```

Comment: Please post your whole query.

Comment: I agree. Post the whole query. We will help you identify the problems in it. We won't write the entire query for you.

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: My query very bad, it dont sum exacly and totals alway change when click next or preview page

Comment: how many records do you have in the result, overally?

Comment: Recently, in my db has about 2 000 records, I think my query can't use, because it's wrong. must be another one

Comment: Dear all, I'm waiting for you